# Is it necessary to call seed() when using random in Python?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I was looking at the following code:

```
from random import choice

for val in range(10):
    a = ','.join(str(choice(range(20))) for idx in range(4))
    print a
```

And realized that I hadn't used seed().  I've been taught to seed the random number generator if you intend to generate different psuedo-random sequences.

I decided to run the code, expecting to the sequence repeated each time. But after several runs of the code, it appears to generate a different sequence each time.

1. Is it really necessary to seed the Python random number generator?  or...
2. Is seed being called by default somewhere?  or...
3. Am I doing something wrong and/or don't understand what's happening?

Comment: Python 2.x docs state that simply importing the module seeds the RNG. IDK why Python 3.x docs removed that bit, but it still seems to be true.

Answer (score 4):

I think seed is just meant to be used

1) so that you can get the same predictable sequence every time if you seed with the same number

2) to feed a better (eg hardware generated) random number in as a start value